# Add different classes to different elements with .hover()

Tags: jquery, jquery-hover

I'm trying to add different classes to different elements when one is on hover in order to create some animations. I expect that when I hover the first element, it also adds the rest of the classes, right now it only adds hover-1 to the first element.

The [link is this](http://linaresdemora.kmturismo.com/explora.html) and the jquery code is:

```
 $('.explorar-seccion:eq(0)').hover(
       function(){ $(this).addClass('hover-1') },
       function(){ $(this).removeClass('hover-1') },
       function(){ $('.explorar-seccion:eq(1)').addClass('hover-2') },
       function(){ $('.explorar-seccion:eq(1)').removeClass('hover-2') },
       function(){ $('.explorar-seccion:eq(2)').addClass('hover-3') },
       function(){ $('.explorar-seccion:eq(2)').removeClass('hover-3') },
       function(){ $('.explorar-seccion:eq(3)').addClass('hover-4') },
       function(){ $('.explorar-seccion:eq(3)').removeClass('hover-4') },
       function(){ $('.explorar-seccion:eq(4)').addClass('hover-5') },
       function(){ $('.explorar-seccion:eq(4)').removeClass('hover-5') }
    );
```

The html is:

```
<a href="/que-ver.html" class="explorar-seccion">
  <!-- Some Code -->
</a>
<a href="/deporte.html" class="explorar-seccion">
  <!-- Some Code -->
</a>
<a href="/historia.html" class="explorar-seccion">
  <!-- Some Code -->
</a>
<a href="/comida.html" class="explorar-seccion">
  <!-- Some Code -->
</a>
<a href="/alojamiento.html" class="explorar-seccion">
  <!-- Some Code -->
</a>
```

**EDIT**
Clarify that it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: What does it and what do you expect it to do?

Comment: I expect that when I hover the first element, it also adds the rest of the classes, right now it only adds hover-1 to the first element.

Comment: [`.hover()`](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) doesn't accept more than 2 arguments, the first for mousein and the second for mouseout

Comment: I don't know if you want it to look like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/5oLkr25e/) or [this](https://jsfiddle.net/pp7f0nf3/)

Comment: I was looking for the first case, but both are more than welcome. Thank you. Can you reply so I can mark your answer as good?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your issue here is that you are trying to use more than 2 arguments for the `.hover()`-function. The first argument is for the `mousein` event and the second for the `mouseout` event.

So your example would correctly like this:

```
$('.explorar-seccion:eq(0)').hover(
   function() {
     $(this).addClass('hover-1');
     $('.explorar-seccion:eq(1)').addClass('hover-2');
     $('.explorar-seccion:eq(2)').addClass('hover-3');
     $('.explorar-seccion:eq(3)').addClass('hover-4');
     $('.explorar-seccion:eq(4)').addClass('hover-5');
   },
   function() {
     $(this).removeClass('hover-1');
     $('.explorar-seccion:eq(1)').removeClass('hover-2');
     $('.explorar-seccion:eq(2)').removeClass('hover-3');
     $('.explorar-seccion:eq(3)').removeClass('hover-4');
     $('.explorar-seccion:eq(4)').removeClass('hover-5');
   }
 );
```

**[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/5oLkr25e/)**

---

When you want to apply a class for each element independently you can go with this:

```
 $('.explorar-seccion').hover(
   function() {
     var $this = $(this),
       eq = $this.index() + 1;
     $this.addClass('hover-' + eq);
   },
   function() {
     var $this = $(this),
       eq = $this.index() + 1;
     $this.removeClass('hover-' + eq);
   }
 );
```

**[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/pp7f0nf3/)**